# How do I create a Json::Value::ArrayIndex in c++?

Tags: c++, json

I want to use a pair of two strings as a key, for example

```
{(key1, key2): value}
```

I tried

```
std::string key1, key2, value;
Json::Value p;
p.append(key1);
p.append(key2);
dict[p] = value;
```

But the compiler complained there is no viable `operator[]`.

I also tried

```
dict[Json::Value::ArrayIndex(p)] = value;
```

But the compiler complained there is no viable way of converting.

What's more, declaring `p` as `Json::Value::ArrayIndex` in the first place will prevent me from using `append` altogether.

So, what is the right way to use an array as a key for my dictionary?

Comment: Which JSON library?

Comment: Sorry to mention, I'm using [JsonCpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp).

Comment: I doubt your example is valid json. According to [json spec](http://json.org), keys must be string.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize that. I used it in Python so I just assumed it's also possible in c++. Plus there is a type called `ArrayIndex`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only strings are valid keys in JSON.

Please consider concatenating the two keys to string, and index using it:

```
dict[key1.asString()+","+key2.asString()] = value;
```

I'm assuming you're not using some sort of weird keys that contains `,` in itself, you need to escape them in that case.

Comment: I realize I was unforgivably mistaken. The `ArrayIndex` is meant to be an "index" of an array, rather than an array "acting like an index". Thank you for clearing this!